# Firefox : features addons

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Firefox is one browser without which i cant even think of developing web application. This comes with so many handy add on and features which makes developers life easy.

However features that Firefox has are huge and not every one is aware about them. So i request you all to add unique features/Add on of Firefox which are/will be helpful for developer.

1. Firebug added then press **Ctr + Shift + F**  : 
   Like very simple that i know is when firebug is added to Firefox 
   press **Ctr + Shift + F** it gives you cross arrow and yellow dash board clicking any element on screen gives all the information about the element in very nice way.
2. Tamper Data : Good add on for analyzing the HTTP request and response
3. Capture Fox : Add on that helps to create the screen cast in simple way.
4. UrlParams : Add on helps to observe the GET and POST parameters sent from the page.

Thanks,

Comment: This is not really a question and may be inappropriate for this forum.

cheers

Comment: Would this not be better suited to SuperUser?  It's not really a development / programming question.  Then again, it's not really any different to asking for development software recommendations either and that seems to be considered acceptable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try here - [firefox add ons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407/firefox-add-ons)

or the super user question here - [must-have-firefox-addons](https://superuser.com/questions/587/must-have-firefox-addons)

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that most of these features are actually built into Firefox now. #1, inspecting an element, is already on the right click menu without any addons. #2 and #4 can be done in a somewhat limited way, by going to Web Console and turning on Net, checking "Log Request and Response Bodies". Then you can click the item for http details.